# Updating all records in single transaction

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, sql-update

Right now I am using Rails AR methods to update a bunch of attributes in a table.

```
RaceWeek.current_week.each { |r| r.update_attributes(:games_won => 0, :games_lost => 0) }
```

I'd prefer to do this more efficiently in a single transaction.  How can this be done?

Comment: current_week is a named_scope that returns all the RaceWeek records that fall between a specified time period.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `update_all`:

```
<model/association>.update_all("games_won = 0, games_lost = 0" )
```

Ps. Use some form of the above, because I do not know what the relation of `RaceWeek` to `current_week` is.

Also see [some examples](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/update_all/class)